# Как можно определить кольцевую цепочку операций?

Tags: sql

Данная задачкa попалась мне на собеседовании:

```
Допустим Ваня должен 100 рублей Коле,
Коля сам должен 100 рублей Кате,
......
Олег должен 100 рублей Ване.
```

Круг замкнулся.
Как можно определить такую кольцевую цепочку операций?

Comment: а причём тут база данных? Найти цикл в ориентированном графе - вполне стандартная задача.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не стоит вандализировать вопрос, получив на него ответ.

Comment: @AK, у вопроса нет ни одной правки. Где ты ухитрился найти вандализм?

Comment: Если модератор по невнимательности востановил ваш вопрос после удаления, то не стоит его дальше игнорировать. Припомните пару дополнительных деталей  связаных с задачей, добавте их в вопос, или для начала комментарием.

Comment: @0xdb посмотрев на варианты ответа, я думал, что это определить можно легко, составив простой запрос, но как видно запрос намного длиннее, если бы я на backend устраивался, то ладно, но зачем этот вопрос задавать android developer, я не знаю

Comment: Ну 10 строк длинным запросом не назовёшь. Может вас о чём другом спрашивали, не sql? Припомните, в каком контексте был задан вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Интервьюер просил составить простенький запрос для иерархической последовательности с нахождением цикла.

Примерно такой:

```sql
with recursiveSubqueryFactoring (name, owesTo) as (
    select name, owesTo
    from testdata
    where name = 'Ваня'
    union all
    select td.name, td.owesTo
    from testdata td
    join recursiveSubqueryFactoring rsf on rsf.name = td.owesTo 
)
search depth first by name set sortCol
cycle name set isCycle to 'y' default 'n'
select 
    case isCycle 
    when 'n' then name||' должен 100 руб. '||owesTo 
    when 'y' then 'но у '||owesTo||' же должник '||name end "кто-кому",
    case isCycle when 'n' then 'вернёт' when 'y' then 'цепочка замкнулась, как быть?' 
    end "что будет"
from recursiveSubqueryFactoring 
order by sortCol;
```

Результат:

```
кто-кому                         что будет                    
-------------------------------- -----------------------------
Ваня должен 100 руб. Коля        вернёт                       
Олег должен 100 руб. Ваня        вернёт                       
Катя должен 100 руб. Олег        вернёт                       
Коля должен 100 руб. Катя        вернёт                       
но у Коля же должник Ваня        цепочка замкнулась, как быть?
```

---

Данные для примера:

```
create table testdata (name varchar (16), owesTo varchar (16));
insert into testdata values ('Ваня','Коля');
insert into testdata values ('Коля','Катя');
insert into testdata values ('Катя','Олег');
insert into testdata values ('Олег','Ваня');
```

Comment: Воу круто. Понадобилось время чтобы всё понять )

Answer (score 1):

[Deadlock](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)  aka Взаимная блокировка

[image: Deadlock]

Comment: В теории баз данных нет понятия deadlock.

Comment: @0xdb А транзакции в эту теорию входят?

Comment: Нет. 2 символа.

Comment: Но они входят в практику работы с БД

Comment: На практике вы работаете с СУБД, вот туда они и входят.